Cop partner supposedly dies, yet is alive and the bad guy
Movie where there is a cop partnership, and they are trying to find the bad guy who has files or paperwork, something like that. One of the partners "dies" and the other one continues to look for the bad guy. He eventually comes to this house thinking that the bad guy will be here. Him and some other cops are walking around the house when all of a sudden the house is on fire and they all have to run out. When the cop finally comes to the front outside of the house, through all of the chaos he sees his "dead" partner walking away from the scene, and he is the bad guy all along. HELP PLEASE!!!

Might be Chaos - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_(2005_Capitol_film)

@tom77 why as a comment? Its a good contender of an answer.

The movie you're looking for seems to be War, starring Jet Li and Jason Statham:

After his partner Tom Lone and family are killed apparently by the
  infamous and elusive assassin Rogue, FBI agent Jack Crawford becomes
  obsessed with revenge as his world unravels into a vortex of guilt and
  betrayal. Rogue eventually resurfaces to settle a score of his own,
  setting off a bloody crime war between Asian mob rivals Chang of the
  Triad's and Yakuza boss Shiro. When Jack and Rogue finally come face
  to face, the ultimate truth of their pasts will be revealed.


I don't think it was Rogue Assassin, especially if you thought Jet Li and Jason Statham were the star ... they were not in this movie, at least not credited.

This was only called Rogue Assassin in certain areas (like New Zealand). Everywhere else it was called War

@Dee - I believe you might be correct. If you add a description of the movie to explain why you think this matches what the OP is looking for then this would be acceptable.
